# MySQL query with multiple IF statements not returning the expected results

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a MySQL query with four IF statements that should set an alias to '1' or '0' according to the conditions inside. Although I don't have any errors, the only IF that's returning correct values is the one with the `is_paid` alias.

I double checked the conditions for the other three aliases and even if they are ok, I still get bogus results.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way I could write the query so I can get the expected results?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT r.doc_number,
       r.doc_date,
       r.due_date,
       r.currency,
       r.amount,
       r.vat,
       r.vatammount,
       (r.amount + r.vatammount) final_amount,
       r.currency,
       b.boq_id,
       b.boq_comp_id,
       b.boq_client_id,
       b.boq_agency,
       b.boq_date,
       b.boq_orders,
       b.receivable_id,
       c.comp_name,
       crm.`cn-name-first`,
       crm.`cn-name-last`,
       bi.inv_path,
       (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id) total_amount_received,
       IF (r.amount + r.vatammount = (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id), '1', '0') AS is_paid,
       IF (CURRENT_DATE >= r.due_date AND r.amount + r.vatammount != (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id), '1', '0') AS is_overdue,
       IF (r.due_date < CURRENT_DATE AND r.amount + r.vatammount != (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id), '1', '0') AS is_outstanding,
       IF (r.due_date = CURRENT_DATE AND r.amount + r.vatammount != (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id), '1', '0') AS is_due_today
FROM receivables r
LEFT JOIN boq b ON b.receivable_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN boq_invoices bi ON bi.inv_boq_id = b.boq_id
LEFT JOIN comp_companies c ON c.comp_id = b.boq_comp_id
LEFT JOIN crm_contacts crm ON crm.contact_id = b.boq_client_id
WHERE r.status = 'active'
  AND r.doc_type = 'inv'
  AND b.boq_status = 'active'
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING is_due_today = '1'
ORDER BY r.doc_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: your `if`s overlap.. `current_date >= r.due_date` and `r.due_date = current_date` will BOTH trigger if the values are equal. so you're basically saying that something due "today" is both overdue AND due today.

Comment: Boolean values are by definition `1` and `0`. There's no need for the `IF` to translate.

Comment: Instead of putting the `SELECT` in each `IF`, I suggest you join with a subquery that calculates `SUM(amount_received) GROUP BY r_id`.

Comment: @MarcB, I agree with you, but I'm setting different aliases and I believed that if I'm doing this it won't matter if the `if` statements are overlapping.

Comment: @MarcB, in order to avoid overlapping should I surround each `IF()` in a `SELECT()` ?

Comment: no, but you could change `>=` to just `>`.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @MarcB, given the fact that `SELECT (CURRENT_DATE > '2016-09-10' AND 1>2)` returns `0`, which is ok, I replaced the IFs like `(SELECT r.due_date = CURRENT_DATE AND (r.amount + r.vatammount != (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id)))` but still not the expected result :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `null`-comparisons. `20 != 0` is `true`, but `20 != null` is `null` (which has the same effect as `false` in `IF`).

```
IF (... r.amount + r.vatammount != 
      (SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) 
       FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id)
   , '1', '0') AS is_overdue,
```

will be `null/false` in cases where you don't have any fitting rows in `receivables_payments` (so probably in cases without any payment), because `SUM(amount_recieved)` will be `null`. So you won't get the correct flag.

You can use `coalesce(value,0)` to get `0` when the value is `null`, so you can compare as you are used to:

```
IF (... r.amount + r.vatammount != 
      COALESCE(SELECT SUM(amount_recieved) 
       FROM receivables_payments WHERE r_id = b.receivable_id),0)
   , '1', '0') AS is_overdue,
```

You should actually do this for all 5 columns that use the sum (the flags and `total_amount_received`), because e.g. in cases where you have a bill for an amount of `0`, the flag `is_paid` will not be correct either.

Comment: I actually got to this version: http://pastebin.com/aNSxM2Hk Works fine for all the aliases, but not for `is_outstanding` and I don't know why.

Comment: @Cosmin `is_outstanding` is exactly the same as `is_overdue` (you just switched `CURRENT_DATE > r.due_date` to `r.due_date < CURRENT_DATE`, which is identical). Do you get different results for these two flags? Or do you want these flags to do something different? Then you should use different code :-P

Answer (score 0):

Your query has general issues:

- First of all there can be many boq per receivable. You group by receivable, but you dont specify which boq data to show (e.g. the maximum boq_id of all boqs belonging to a receivable with `max(b.boq_id)`). So you simply show one of the matching boq_id, one of the matching boq_comp_id, etc., all arbitrarily chosen. They don't even have to belong to the same record, so you could get the boq_id from one record, the boq_comp_id from another, etc.
- Then you outer join boq. So you want to show receivables even when they don't have any associated boq. But in your WHERE clause you demand `b.boq_status = 'active'`. Outer-joined records' columns are NULL. So no outer joined record matches and you dismiss them thus right away. Either you *want* to outer-join, then put the condition in the ON clause, or you don't, then use INNER JOIN (or short JOIN for that matter).

Now to your evaluations:

- is_overdue is when the paid amount doesn't match the amount to pay and due_date is today or past.
- is_outstanding is when the paid amount doesn't match the amount to pay and due_date is past.
- is_due_today is when the paid amount doesn't match the amount to pay and due_date is today.

Looks okay to me. Well, you'd count overpayments as unpaid, but maybe they are not possible in your database. If an amount is not met and due_date is today, both is_overdue and is_due_today are set. If an amount is not met and due_date was last week, both is_overdue and is_outstanding are set.

Isn't that the case? What is your actual issue with them?

Comment: There is only one receivable / boq. Outstanding means the the invoice is not paid but it's due date hasn't been met yet.

Comment: I know it's one one receivable per boq, but it's several boq per receivable. Which is why you cannot show *the* boq for a receivable. So which boq do you want to show for a receivable? The latest? The oldest? So far you haven't told the DBMS. If you want the `due_date` for `is_outstanding` to be in the *future*, then make it `IF (r.due_date > CURRENT_DATE AND ...`

Comment: No, outstanding means that `r.due_date < CURRENT_DATE` and the paid amount doesn't match the amount to pay, so the condition is well written.

Comment: Am I asking too much to change the query on pastebin to match your logic?

Comment: You mean to magically turn the `>` into a `<`? :-D Or to pick a particular boq per receivable? In that case you'd have to say which. As to the outer joins: Do you *want* to outer join? Do you want to show receivables that have no boq? And are `boq_comp_id` and `boq_client_id` always filled or can they be null?

Comment: Turning the `>` into a `<` wouldn't make any sense because it doesn't respect what `outstanding` means. Also, there is one boq per receivable and one receivable per boq. So I really don't know what to change :)

Comment: I don't understand. One time you say that outstanding means the due date hasn't been met yet, i.e. the due date is still in the future, i.e. `due_date > CURRENT_DATE`. Then you say  outstanding means that `due_date < CURRENT_DATE`, i.e. the due date is in the past.

Comment: As to the boq: So it's a 1:1 relation between the tables? So there must be exactly one boq per receivable. A very rare thing. Usually you would have only one table then. Or is it 1:{0,1}, i.e. there *can* be no more than one boq per receivable? Then again: Would you want to show a receivable that has no active boq?

Comment: You were right, it's `>` but I also needed to change the order of `1` and `0` for the `IF()`. No, I don't want to show a receivable that has no active boq.

Comment: Change 1 and 0??? You had `IF amount unpaid AND due date in the past THEN yes ELSE no`. I suggested to make it `IF amount unpaid AND due date in the future THEN yes ELSE no`. But you changed it to `IF amount unpaid AND due date in the future THEN no ELSE yes`, which translates to `IF amount paid OR due date not in the future THEN yes ELSE no`. That again makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I must go to bed. As there cannot be more than one active boq per receivable, the non-aggregated boq values are no issue. And as you only want receivables with active boqs, you can turn outer joins into inner joins. Then you should do what Barmar suggested: Join the paid sums. This may be it: http://pastebin.com/AqnS5W5j